# Partially deallocating structs/classes in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, memory, heap-memory, dynamic-memory-allocation

Is there a way to partially deallocate structs/classes in C++? I was trying to build some sort of a new pointer in C++ that point to RefCount

```cpp
template<typename T>
struct RefCount {
    unsigned int ref;
    T data;
};

template<typename T>
class ptr {
    RefCount<T> *m_object;
};
```

that can give safe access to the the object being pointed to whenever `ref > 0` and gives the user the ability to make `ref == 0` but without destroyng all instances of RefCount first.

i thought about destroying the `data` part (i will call it the "tail" of the RefCount) first but actually keeping the `ref` part allocated in memory incase `T` was very large and i didn't want it to take unescary part of memory.

please note this structure does NOT **behave** the same as std::shared_ptr.

- Does partially deallocating the "tail" of a struct/class in C++ work?

new and delete don't provide a way to this as far as I know, is there a way to use a function like malloc() to do this kind of trickery? hoping to do this no later than C++11.

the reason i DON'T want to use the 2 pointer approach (pointing to `data` and `ref` as 2 different objects) is for performance. and I also do not want to reallocate a new object that holds the bool alone for obvious reasons (it breaks the way the structure works).

Comment: *NOT **behave** the same as std::shared_ptr. YES, it behaves like `std::shared_ptr` + `std::weak_ptr`.

Comment: but i don't want the overhead a shared_ptr have of 2 pointers to 2 objects

Comment: shared_ptr doesn't have 2 pointers, neither 1.

Comment: *for performance. Have you measured it before redesigning smart pointers?

Comment: it might not have 2 but still got overhead

Comment: this might be useful beyond “redesigning smart pointers” i just brought up an intuitive example here

Comment: What you are describing is alomost exactly what std::shared_ptr does.  It keeps the reference count 'alive' as long as std::weak_ptr's point to the structure.  For this purpose, it keeps 2 reference counts, one for 'shared' references and one for 'weak' references.  Beware!  shared_ptr keeps the 'header' with reference counts in a separately allocated block, UNLESS you allocated memory using 'std::make_shared()', in which case a single  block of memory is allocated from the heap.

Comment: No you can't use `malloc` either when you are managing objects with constuctors. But most of all do you have a PROVEN performance issue (with std::shared_ptr)?. If you have not you are prematurely optimizing (close to a sin in C++). Use a profiler to profile ALL your code (built in release mode with optimizations on etc.). I dare to predict that your actual bottleneck is somewhere else entirely.

Comment: i see the similarities but i could have used a bool named valid instead of the ref count to see if the pointer is safe to access even if it is not NULL, the point of the example to see if truncating an allocated struct on the heap possible in any way.

Comment: Also do not underestimate the power of modern compilers : [What has my compiler done for me lately, by Matt Godbolt](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bSkpMdDe4g4)

Comment: i can find the same problem here in truncating arrays in memory not just in pointers, the question can have more applications if theres a solution for this

Comment: The one way to change the size of an allocated block is to use malloc and realloc.  But then you MUST use in-place new and in-place delete to initialize and clean up your payload.

Comment: i think you didnt catch the problem, you can have many ‘ptr’ instances but none of them can know if the pointer is freed unless u have a bool saying it has been freed

Comment: Also don't get us wrong, we're not critizing you from trying to do what you are doing. Any effort is good effort because you are learning ;) It is just that some of us have decades of experience and want to make sure you are not introducing some buggy code

Comment: An atomic reference count is as good as a bool.

Comment: there exists no function in the standard library other than malloc or calloc that can partially destruct a structure?

Comment: No, these are the only functions that manipulate the heap.  Thank god!

Comment: i see the worry for buggy code im just trying to see if im missing something, thank you in any case.

Comment: hhhhh thank god indeed, but that doesn’t  stop us from creating another structure for a heap that satisfy this kind of behaviour right?

Comment: If you want to be able to "Partially" delete datastructures you have to build the datastructures in parts. And std::unique_ptr/std::shared_ptr aren't really all that bad.  Also for all other C++ programmers out there (including your future self) I think it is best if you build up your designs based on standard library types (like std::shared_ptr), because it leads to code that others will be able to understand (quickly) too

Comment: ill make sure of that in future.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The C++ memory allocation APIs do not provide for such a functionality, neither the standard library Allocator interface, nor the `operator new`/`operator delete` and `new`/`delete` expression interfaces.

C's `realloc`, which you can use in conjunction with `malloc` and `free`, technically permits this, but I think standard library implementations usually ignore a request to shrink the allocation. However, you can't use `realloc` because it isn't guaranteed not to move the allocation, even when the new size is smaller than the old one.

You can of course write your own allocator to provide something similar. What the performance and memory overhead impact of such a functionality on the allocator is, is a different question. I think this is typically not considered worth the performance penality incurred for the allocator.

In any case, the language does not permit partially releasing storage of an object, so you can't have the `RefCount` structure. Instead you would need to manually store the two subobjects in the allocated storage, as an array of `std::byte` or `unsigned char`, with placement-news and explicit destructor calls, and then have `m_object` point to this underlying storage array from which you can access the two subobjects with `reinterpret_cast` and `std::launder`.

Comment: so the big idea can be done? getting a raw block of memory and then constructing 2 different objects next to each other on it then destructing only one of them and realeasing the part of memory not needed?

Comment: @Ak2399 Destroying the object can always be done. Releasing its storage is only possible if the allocator from which you obtained the storage originally supports it. C++ `new`/`delete` and the standard library _Allocator_ interface do _not_ support that and `malloc`/`realloc`/`free` usually just ignore requests to shrink allocations, as I wrote in my answer.

Comment: @Ak2399 Forgot to add to the answer: You can't use `realloc` for this purpose though because it may relocate the allocation even if the new size is smaller than the old one.

Comment: The benefit from truly releasing that partial storage is also questionable. In particular, the released memory would not be able to hold another, new `RefCount <T>`. It may be much more efficient to simply call the destructor on `data`, and resurrect another `T` when needed with a placement new. In truly performance critical code one would probably write one's own allocator for `RefCount`, perhaps preparing a pool of objects ready-to-use beforehand. Memory be damned ;-).